# Downgrade from OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos

I totally messed up today and I hope that you can help me. I have the latest version of the mbp. Since this is my first apple pc, I thought, that I can just install the developer preview, despite having a developer account. Everything worked fine and today I wanted to update to the new GM. I wanted a clean install, so I burned the image to a usb stick and installed it in the boot menu. Unfortunately it didn't work, so I deleted the hard disk (the macintosh part) and tried again. Luckily I had boot camp installed and can now use windows 8.1. Now I'm trying to reinstall mac os. I just found out, that I cant restore it, as the restore had changed to mavericks preview, which will also check, if I'm a registered developer. A USB Stick and a DVD didn't install me Mountain Lion nor Mavericks Preview. In fact the USB stick wasn't even recogonized. I was using the .dmg (you'll find in the internet) and the windows program TransMac. So do you have any idea, how I can solve this? I don't have a backup. Is there a cheap version of becoming a registered developer like for ios? Or can I just wait for the release of Mavericks?

Comment: There is a Answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93850/roll-back-from-os-x-mavericks-or-any-newer-os-to-mountain-lion

Comment: You could also try using [Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1433) to create a recovery partition on an external drive, but I'm not sure if it would be recognized either.

Comment: Ok, now it worked. I just used the CMD+Alt+R methode. The loading took quite a while. That's why I assumed yesterday that this is also not working. Thanks for your help.