# Downgrade from OSX 10.10 Yosemite Beta to OSX 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: time-machine, macos

I downloaded the Beta version of Yosemite, but I'm finding that some of my key programs are running properly. I keep regular backups to a Time Capsule. How do I downgrade back to 10.9?

EDIT: 21.5 inch iMac, Late 2013. Original OS: Mavericks

Comment: You might add what type of Mac (year, original OS, etc) you're using as the answer is somewhat dependent on that info.

Comment: Off topic, sorry - you have a dev account (or you could not install it), so you need to ask there.  That, and never install a first beta on your only machine...

Comment: @stuffe In the meta post about this it says this question specifically *is* allowed?

Comment: @BritishColour The Meta post in question is a discussion piece that's actually from Mavericks with the names changed, and the bit you are referring to is part of someone's answer but isn't necessarily a canonical source, indeed the other answer (with more votes) says no full stop.  I think the best place is the Dev forums, they are specifically there to discuss this sort of thing, and you won't get bumped from them.

Comment: @stuffe Ah I see. Never mind :)

Comment: Given the beta is now open to the public, which might not necessarily have access to the developer forums, I suggest this question gets opened again, especially considering there seems to be quite some interest on it.

Comment: [Can I reinstall Mavericks after I got Yosemite?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135677/8546) – please note, there are multiple questions.

Comment: [Roll back from … any newer OS …](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/93850/8546) (2013-06-13)