# How do I downgrade from Yosemite 10.10 to Mavericks 10.9?

Tags: macos, downgrade

I have the new Yosemite. How do i downgrade to the last version?

I really don't like it. Lost Yahoo messenger and a lot of extras I had on my old operating system.

Comment: Do you mean iOS or Mac OS X? Makes a big difference. iOS 8 is definitely not able to be downgraded to iOS 7. If you mean Mac OS X Yosemite then it is possible. 1. Please check your spelling and make sure your question is more understandable since it is quite hard to read...
2. In general: Google is your friend, same goes for YouTube, which actually is the same somehow...
3. I guess it may be possible if you do the downgrade like the upgrade. So like downloading the installation .dmg from the appStore. The problem is that Mavericks won't show up in your Mac App Store since you have got a newer

Comment: Do you mean iOS 8 (on your iPhone/iPad) or OS X 10.10/Yosemite (on your Mac)? I've edited your question assuming OS X, please fix if necessary.

Comment: A word to the wise -- it may be too late for you, but always read as many forums and news columns (and for that matter the source page for any app or extension you love) to see what is and isn't supported in a new version of an Operating System. <-- **BEFORE** upgrading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I downgrade to Mavericks after installing Yosemite?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135677/can-i-downgrade-to-mavericks-after-installing-yosemite)

Comment: The problem with Yosemite is that it is NOT an upgrade (at least as far as UI goes) ... it takes the Mac OS interface backwards ... to the world of Windows. It just feels incredibly ugly and klunky.

Answer (score 6):

> Backup Mavericks using Time Machine first (if possible)
>
> Follow these steps to get a copy of Mac OS X Mavericks:
>
> 1. Open the App Store.
> 2. Enter your Apple ID and Password and click Sign In (if App Store requests it).
> 3. Click Purchases.
> 4. Scroll down to find Mavericks.
> 5. Click Download.
>
> Now that you have downloaded the Mavericks file you will find it inside Applications.
>   Revert to Mavericks by creating a Mac OS X USB boot drive.
>
> [How to make a bootable Mavericks install drive](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-make-bootable-mavericks-install-drive-3475042/)
>
> You can use this file to turn an 8GB USB Flash into a Mac OS X Mavericks boot drive. With this USB Boot Drive you can wipe the hard drive on your Mac, and install a fresh copy of Mac OS X Mavericks. If you have your Mavericks Time Machine backup, it can be used to reinstall all your files and programs (otherwise you’ll need to setup your Mac from scratch using the files you backed up to an external drive or cloud storage solution).
>
> Using a Mac OS X Mavericks boot drive to perform a fresh Mac OS X installation
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac (Choose Apple > Shut Down).
> 2. Insert the Mavericks USB Flash Drive into your Mac.
> 3. Startup the Mac while holding down the Alt key.
> 4. Choose the USB Flash Drive Volume.
> 5. Choose Utilities > Disk Utility on the Install Mac OS X window.
> 6. Select your main Volume in the sidebar. Now click Erase > Erase (warning, this removes everything on the volume).
> 7. Click Disk Utility > Quit Disk Utility.
> 8. Tap Continue on the Install OS X window.

Check out this [MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/revert-back-mavericks-from-yosemite-3581872/). It explains each step in detail.

Note: In some rare instances, it may be necessary to format the Macintosh HD partition before installing Mavericks. **This will erase your entire hard drive ** so be sure to back up any files you need before going this route. I've outlined the steps to do this below:

1.) Boot the Mac from the USB you made using the steps above. 
2.) Open Disk Utility and erase the drive entitled (Usually) "Macintosh HD". You can rename it whatever you like. 
3.) Install Mavericks.

Answer (score 3):

If you had a Time Machine backup you can revert pretty easily:
Choose Apple menu > Restart, and then hold down the Command (⌘) and R keys while the computer restarts.
Select “Restore from a Time Machine Backup,” and then click Continue.
Select your Time Machine backup disk.
Select the Time Machine backup you want to restore. To restore your computer to the state it was in before you installed the new version of Mac OS X, choose the most recent backup.
Follow the onscreen instructions.

If you didn't you're in for a much tougher time.  I'd recommend you visit the Genius Bar at the Apple Store. But basically, you will have to erase your entire hard drive and re-install the OS X version of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

I think previously you can still do it before Apple remove Mavericks from their server. By the way, thank god if you have a backup of Mavericks Bootable Drive because you can downgrade it with these steps [Downgrade from Yosemite to Mavericks Guide](http://www.cydiawater.com/downgrade-from-yosemite-to-mavericks-guide/) at anytime you want.

Comment: Hi, Vega! Welcome to Ask Different! In general, we try and avoid link-only answers. If that link gets changed for any reason, your answer suddenly stops being an answer. Please add some of the details from the link not your actual answer. Thanks!