# From Yosemite to Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac-mini, downgrade

I originally bought my Mac mini on Yosemite. I wanted to downgrade to mavericks, and on this website I read that if I went into core services and changed my SystemVersion.plist from 10.10 to 10.8 and download Mavericks from the AppStore, I would have mavericks. Guess what? App Store doesn't even work! All of my apple apps don't work because it says I need 10.10, including text edit. Can someone please help me? I even called apple and they didn't know what to do. HELP!!!!

Comment: You have Yosemite and wanted to downgrade to Yosemite - please edit the question to make it understandable

Comment: @Helppppp Sorry to hear that. That was my [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159419/install-mavericks-on-second-partition-in-yosemite-only-system/159556#159556). But the question clearly states that the Mac (MacBook Pro 2012) **can** run Mavericks. My answer is not valid for Macs which only run with newer systems (like your MacMini)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I downgrade from Yosemite 10.10 to Mavericks 10.9?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153122/how-do-i-downgrade-from-yosemite-10-10-to-mavericks-10-9)

Comment: @GrahamPerrin It's no duplicate. The title (it's not really a question) is misleading. It should be altered to: How do I recover my system install after trying to downgrade from Yosemite to Mavericks erroneously (following the instructions in this [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159419/install-mavericks-on-second-partition-in-yosemite-only-system/159556#159556))

Answer (score 1):

Restart your MacMini to recovery mode by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

Open Utilities/Terminal in the menubar

[image]

*Please replace "YourMainVolume" with the name of your main Mac volume (probably "Macintosh HD") in the following commands.*

If you made a backup of your `SystemVersion.plist` (like advised in my [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159419/install-mavericks-on-second-partition-in-yosemite-only-system/159556#159556)) enter:

```
rm "/Volumes/YourMainVolume/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"
```

and hit <kbd>↵</kbd>, then enter:

```
mv "/Volumes/YourMainVolume/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist.backup" "/Volumes/YourMainVolume/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"
```

and hit <kbd>↵</kbd>.
Enter `exit`, hit <kbd>↵</kbd>, quit `Terminal` and restart your Mac.

If you didn't make a backup of your `SystemVersion.plist` enter:

```
vi "/Volumes/YourMainVolume/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"
```

and revert the edits you made previously. ([vi Quick reference](http://www.astrohandbook.com/ch20/vi_guide.html))

Quit `Terminal` and restart your Mac.