# Yosemite's Preview.app goes to top of document when PDF changes

Tags: pdf, preview, latex

I use Preview.app to view PDFs which I am creating with `pdflatex`.
In OSX Mavericks, whenever the PDF changed I would switch windows away from Preview and then back, and the view would update, scrolling to the top of the **current page** when in continuous scroll mode.

Now after updating to Yosemite, Preview.app always goes back up to the **top of the document** whenever the PDF file is updated. This is extremely annoying and I have found no way to get the old behaviour back. Any ideas? If I choose Single Page mode (<kbd>⌘2</kbd>) this seems to stay on the same page, but ideally I would like to keep continuous scroll...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please [let Apple know](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) about this regression in Preview.app's behaviour in OS X 10.10.

If you have an Apple Developer ID, you can also report this via [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have created bug report 18779386 (but don't know if anyone else can access that).

Comment: Thank you for reporting the bug. No-one outside of Apple will be able to see the detail of the bug report but knowing the bug number is helpful for those encountering the problem. [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com) is also available for sharing public bug reports.

Comment: Thanks to all. I felt stupid after accepting the "free" upgrade to 10.10 and seeing that Preview is now half-broken (this is how I feel). I've let Apple know. Is there a way to install an earlier version of Preview until Apple fix the new one?

Comment: Reverting just Preview.app is unlikely to work. You may be able to [revert back to OS X 10.9](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135677/can-i-downgrade-to-mavericks-after-installing-yosemite-beta-developer-preview). The safest option is to bulk restore from a pre-Yosemite back-up.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered through [the TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43057/macosx-pdf-viewer-automatic-reload-on-file-modification) that [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) handles this quite well. Just make sure to check the "Check for file changes" option in the Sync tab of preferences, and you might need to set the hidden option mentioned in the TeX StackExchange post.

Answer (score 0):

At least in 10.10.3, if one closes the existing pdf before recreating the new version, opening the new version returns the view to the page that was previously displayed.  It is though a pain to have to remember to close the existing pdf each time, then later go to 'Open Recent'.